# Install Windows on fully encrypted Ubuntu machine

Tags: dual-boot

like the title suggest I want to install Windows 7 beside Ubuntu for gaming purposes.
Ubuntu 12.10 has been installed and completely encrypted with **LUKS/LVM**. Bootloader is GRUB. Hard drive is ext2.
Is it even possible to install Windows now? Cause I really wanna play games and if it doesn't work I have to dump Ubuntu but I really like it.
Wine and VM's aren't working either.

I've asked this question on so many boards but no one seems to be able to help me.

Comment: Installing Windows will corrupt your boot and you won’t be able to boot from Ubuntu. Of course you will be able to repair grub manually by certain softwares. Be aware of this problem.

Comment: See [How can I repair grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) for this issue.

Comment: Already heard about this problem so I'm glad you sent me the link.

Answer (score 2):

As Windows needs a NTFS partition to work you need to free some space on your hard drive. This new and free part won't be encrypted by Ubuntu, if you format it with GParted in a live session. I have never done it before, but it should work like this. You can even access your ubuntu file system via FreeOTFE within Windows

Comment: Thanks! Can I also encrypt the new made partition with TrueCrypt?

Comment: Sure, but then you need the TrueCrypt bootloader to encrypt the drive at boot. See here for more information: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-encryption